# Laravel after_or_equal validation returns wrong status code for date before today

Tags: laravel, validation

does anyone have similar issue?

I have a route to the controller method with specific request. Inside the request I am validating the date format like this:

`'date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:today'`

when I send in Postman the date which is today or later everything is fine and code 200 is returned. When I send the date before today api sends also 200 code but it never hits the method code (tried to check with dd) but returns the home page of the api.

Steps To Reproduce:

1. Create api route
2. create controller and method with custom request
3. set authorize() return value to true
4. set rule() return value to `['date' => 'required|date_format:y-m-d|after_or_equal:today']`
5. send request to the api (i.e. using Postman) with date before today and after

I am using Laravel framework 7.13.0

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic
If your request is a regular Http request, failing validation will just redirect you to the previous page with errors in the session data. Could you please add the request details you are sending through postman?

Comment: It is a post request with raw JSON type like this:
{ "date": "2020-05-10" }
Right, good point, I didn't add the accept key to the header. It works, thx @msmahon

Comment: What are your request headers? Is your content type application/json?

Comment: Yes, I have missed the header. Thx once again

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper JSON request headers so that laravel returns a JSON response with errors instead of a redirect.